# typescript uses .expo/types/router.d.ts in dev and expo-router module in github actions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I'm using `expo SDK 49` with `react-native` and `expo router v2`

When I run `tsc --noEmit --pretty` locally I get the following error.

[image]

Here is the code

[image]

However, when the same command is ran in github actions then there is no error.

It says the href type is declared in `.expo/types/router.d.ts`

If I import Href from `expo-router`

`import { Link, Href } from "expo-router";`

and update the params to be `Href<string`

[image]

Then it works locally but in github actions it says

`Module '"expo-router"' has no exported member 'Href'.`

Can someone explain to meet what is happening here?
Why does it look into `router.d.ts` in local but in `github actions` it looks into the `expo-router` module?

My file structure:
In root there is an `.expo` directory which has the router file in it.
What is the purpose of the `expo` directory?

I just realized in my `.gitignore` by default it ignores the `.expo` directory so I'm guessing that's what's causing the issue since the github actions do not have `.expo` directory.

What is the `.expo` directory and why is it added to `.gitignore` by default?
[image]

[image]