# what is the .expo directory for and why is it added to .gitignore by default

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using `expo SDK 49` and by default it adds `.expo` to the `.gitignore` file but this creates an issue in `github actions` since github actions does not have access to that directory.

What is the `.expo` directory used for?

Why is it added to `.gitignore` by default?

Can we just delete the `.expo` directory?

Note: This is my original question which led me to these questions:

[typescript uses .expo/types/router.d.ts in dev and expo-router module in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76823034/typescript-uses-expo-types-router-d-ts-in-dev-and-expo-router-module-in-github)

UPDATE:
I think the doc explanations and the `README` are outdated because there is no `settings.json` file and there are other files created that are not in the documentation.

Maybe because I am using the new `SDK 49`?

Here is what is created for me

[image]

And in my original issue, it is the `router.d.ts` that is interfering with my `typescript` checking.

Comment: What issue are you seeing in github actions? What action is set up to view .expo?

Comment: @scatter there is a link at the bottom of the question which explains the original error

Answer (score 0):

If you open your `.expo` folder you'll find a README inside and it'll answer all your questions about this folder:

> Why do I have a folder named ".expo" in my project?
> The ".expo" folder is created when an Expo project is started using "expo start" command.
>
> What do the files contain?
>
> - "devices.json": contains information about devices that have recently opened this project. This is used to populate the "Development sessions" list in your development builds.
> - "settings.json": contains the server configuration that is used to serve the application manifest.
>
> Should I commit the ".expo" folder?
>
> No, you should not share the ".expo" folder. It does not contain any information that is relevant for other developers working on the project, it is specific to your machine.
> Upon project creation, the ".expo" folder is already added to your ".gitignore" file.

So, as this folder is in your `.gitignore` you can safelly delete it because it does not contains any relevant information and it's regenerated by expo when you start your app again

Comment: just updated my question @NoNam4

Comment: I think this is a bug in new expo sdk49, take a look in [this](https://github.com/expo/router/issues/746#issuecomment-1634715971) temporary sollution I've found and see if it helps you

Comment: also, take a look into [this](https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/typed-routes/) doc page